# How to make a binary tree from in order and preorder

Tags: python

I want to make a binary tree from a given in order and pre order list. For example pre = [3,9,1,2,20,15,7] and in = [1,9,2,3,15,30,7]

I know how to be begin so
The first element in pre order is the root
Split in order at the root. What’s before that is the left sun tree and what’s after is the right sub tree.
What I’m having trouble with is how to recurse through the left and right

This is what I have right now

```
class tree: 
    def build(self, pre, in):
        if self._value == None:
            self._value = pre[0]
        left = in[:self._value] 
        right = in[self._value+1:]
        return self
```

Comment: Having split the in-order list at the root, you then have in-order lists for each child. To recurse, you will additionally need pre-order lists for each child. How can you find those?

Comment: @kaya3 so I would also have to split the preorder at the same spot as the in order except for left which would maybe be [1:self._value+1] ?

Comment: You will have to split the pre-order at the correct point; note that splitting at `value` is wrong, you have to find the *index* of that value in order to split there.

Comment: oh yeah forgot about that so I would just have the function calling itself except at the “new”  pre and in order